# My Insert data in PDO wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to do is if the user fill the information in the form and click the submit button it will store the data in the database. No problem in the connection in database i tested it.

My problem now is it wont save at all can anyone help me fix whats wrong with the code?

index.php:

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
#Picture {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
#imgInp { display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentSrc = $('#Picture').attr('src');
    if(currentSrc==null || currentSrc==""){        
    $('#Picture').attr('src','http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg');

   $("#Picture").on('click', function() {
       $("#imgInp").trigger('click')}
   )}


    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<img id="Picture" name="Picture" data-src="#" /> <br />
<input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/*" /><br />
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age" /><br />
Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female" />Female<br />
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
    $age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : null;
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null;
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : null;
    $picture = isset($_FILES['Picture']) ? $_FILES['Picture'] : null;

    $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, profile_pic) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :Picture)";

    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
    $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
    $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
    $query->bindParam(':Picture', $picture);

    $results = $query->execute();

}
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? Server-side error.log?

Comment: The form says `action="index.php"`, but the insert script is `header.php`.

Comment: This is the 3rd time you post this, 2 of them were deleted, why?

Comment: Add `$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. You're not checking for errors and assuming everything works.

Comment: If you would have tried troubleshooting your code without the JS and tried it as pure PHP/SQL, you'll be able to pinpoint exactly where your code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to this -

```
<form method="post" action="header.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Let's hope this will solve the OP's issue. It's the 3rd time he/she has posted the same question.

Comment: header.php is already included in index.php. This doesn't seem the problem to me.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Then use: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: I see that @ThinkDifferent, that is why I asked him about console and log errors earlier.

Comment: @ TiMESPLiNTER You should escape the output `echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Comment: Sure, escaping's better, but it's not the root of the problem and is the least of the OP's issue right now; it's merely a "detail". ;-)